# OpAmp Spice Model: Offset vs Common Mode Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, ltspice, spice, dc-offset

The spice Model of the OPA350 specifies that the DC Offset Voltage vs Input Common Mode voltage is implemented in the model. If I do the simulation however, all I can see is a linear trace, when x axis is the common voltage and y axis the DC offset. See image in ltspice.

[image]

As it is a Rail-to-Rail Input, I was more expecting to see two different voltages, depending which input stage is currently used. See second image (exampl of another rail-to-rail amplifier)

[image]

So what am I doing wrong, or is it just the spice model missing that, even though it is written in the lib file ?

Comment: It says it models "INPUT OFFSET VOLTAGE VS. INPUT COMMON-MODE VOLTAGE (Vos vs. Vcm)".  From your results, it looks like it models it as a linear effect (CMRR) only. You could dig into the model itself.

Comment: Spehro : And what should I do in the model ?

Comment: I just suggest trying to figure it out. Modifying it would be advanced. If you want to give it a go, the LTSpice mailing list folks would be my go-to, sorry SE.

Comment: Where is that image from? I don't see a figure like that in the [OPA350 datasheet on ti.com](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa350.pdf?ts=1593530314523&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FOPA350%253FkeyMatch%253DOPA350%2526tisearch%253DSearch-EN-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN). Please link to the full datasheet you are using for context.

Comment: I wrote: ".. (example of another rail-to-rail amplifier)..". 
I expect the same for the OPA350. Especially that my real world measurement confirms me that. So something wrong with the spice model

Answer (score 1):

You are using bipolar supply for *OPAx350 High-Speed, **Single-Supply**, Rail-to-Rail Operational Amplifiers MicroAmplifier Series*. If you change `V1` to be `5` and `V3` to be 0, you'll see a different picture. If you want to change to offset voltage, you need to dig into the model, as suggested. For that you'll need much more than simply change a `.param`, as the model is quite involved. You could start at the `VOS_DRIFT_OPA350` subcircuit, then see how it fits in the rest of the netlist (I see `XV_OS` in the main subcircuit), but I don't feel particularly interested in unravelling the rest. If you wish to do so, by all means.

Comment: Dual supply or single supply does not make any change, the simulated values are the same for 0-5V common voltage. I don't want to change the offset, I want to simulate it correctly, as the spice model clearly says that it should contain : "INPUT OFFSET VOLTAGE VS. INPUT COMMON-MODE VOLTAGE (Vos vs. Vcm)".

Comment: I see mV instead of uV but, yes, it doesn't seem to be implemented very well. Just tested with other opamps from LTspice's database and some have, some don't. Maybe the model for TINA has it?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The modeled input offset voltage is 120 uV because that's the offset when the input is at 0 volts. The OPA350 has a typical value of +/- 150 uV.

If you wish to adjust the \$V_{OS}\$ value in the model you should be able to find a way but I'm no expert on how you will find it in LTSpice because I use micro-cap and it's easy to make modifications to model parameters in that sim package.

If you wish to model the type of non-linear change in \$V_{OS}\$ as depicted in your 2nd picture, this can be achieved with a little care and skill by a combination of VCVS's and some limiting circuits. Like I say I can easily do this in micro-cap but, someone might know how to do it in LTSpice.

Comment: Andy: the voltage you see on the plot is already divided by the Gain. So that means Offset of 120 uV at 0 V common voltage. 
I do not understand what you want to tell me with the external circuitry. I do not want to implement any external circuitry "making" it compatible to see how the offset changes in function of the applied Common Voltage. I was more wondering why the simulation does not show that correctly, when the spice model clearly states that it should.

Comment: @newstudent I'll alter my words to reflect what you point out. Simulation models try to remain simple. Regards offset voltage they are simple and won't dynamically adjust the offset voltage as you might expect in real life.